# show that function is convex

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. Show that

$$f\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
+\infty & \mbox{ if }x\in\left(0,\infty\right)\\
0 & \mbox{ if }x=0\\
-\infty & \mbox{ if }x\in\left(-\infty,0\right)
\end{cases}$$

is convex.

Comment: How do you define $\infty + (-\infty)$?

Comment: define $+\infty -\infty =0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> define $+\infty−\infty=0$

In that case the function is not convex. We have

$$\infty = f\left(\frac13\right) = f \left(\frac23\cdot 1 + \frac13\cdot (-1)\right),$$

but

$$\frac23f(1) + \frac13 f(-1) = \frac23\infty + \frac13(-\infty) = \infty - \infty = 0 < \infty$$

with that definition. For a convex function, we'd have $f(1/3) \leqslant \frac23 f(1) + \frac13 f(-1)$.

Comment: what happen if we define $+\infty -\infty =+\infty$

Comment: In that case, we get a convex function.